# Boost 1.58 installed, but boost_thread and boost_locale missing

Tags: apt, c++, cmake, boost

Trying to build a project that requires boost. I get the following error:

```
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.58.0

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_thread
          boost_locale

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
```

If I run

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

I get

```
libboost-all-dev is already the newest version (1.58.0.1ubuntu1).
```

So I don't know what to do here. How can install these particular boost packages, or reinstall the whole boost package?

edit: Also, if I run apt-get remove libboost-all-dev , nothing seems to get removed. Running apt-get install libboost-all-dev afterwards still tells me I have the newest version.

Comment: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_{thread,locale}.a` are provided by  `libboost-{thread,locale}1.58-dev` which are installed via `libboost-all-dev`. Maybe you should check if the build system has more detailed logs.

Comment: "Maybe you should check if the build system has more detailed logs" what does that mean?

Comment: I don't know which build system this is (CMake?). If you ran `./configure`, there will be a `config.log`. CMake has something like `CMakeError.log`, I think. The log file will have details on the actual command ran to check this and what errors it got.

Comment: I found the CMakeError.log but I don't know what to do with it. I removed all my boost files, but still apt-get seems to tihnk I have it installed and refused to reinstall boost

Comment: `libboost-all-dev` is simply a meta-package. It depends on various `libboost-*-dev` packages which in turn depend on `libboost-*X.Y-dev` packages to provide the actual libraries. Reinstalling just the `libboost-all-dev` package is effectively meaningless.

Comment: As for `CMakeError.log`, add it to the question, or if it is too long, post it to  https://paste.ubuntu.com/  and add the link here.